# IOS Push ViewController from AppDelegate.h

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm using a StoryBoard which contains various ViewControllers and a TableViewController, one in particular is ImageViewController which just displays an image. My DetailViewController contains a UIWebView, here I have a link, when pressed I am trying to load a my ImageViewController.

The link is

## View Image

`

In AppDelegate.m I get the filename value by handling handleOpenURL.

I'm new to IOS and struggling how to load my ImageViewController from the handleOpenURL method in AppDelegate.m.

My code is:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

{

```
NSString *param = [keyValueParm objectForKey:@"filename"];
NSLog(@"Param: %@",param);

ImageViewController *imageViewController =[[ImageViewController alloc]init];
imageViewController.imageString = param;

UIViewController *root = self.window.rootViewController;
[root.navigationController pushViewController:imageViewController animated:YES];
return true;
```

}

At present nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should't implement the `application:handleOpenURL:` method. Not only it is deprecated, but what it does is ask the application delegate to allow opening an URL in the browser.

What you want to do instead is implement the `UIWebViewControllerDelegate` protocol in the `DetailViewController`. Specifically you should implement the `– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method. In it:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
   [ImageViewController *imageViewController =[[ImageViewController alloc]init];
   imageViewController.imageString = param;
   [root.navigationController pushViewController:imageViewController animated:YES];

   return YES;
}
```

In this method, the `UIWebView` instance asks its delegate for permission to open an url.

Hope it helps

Comment: I cant get it working. I made sure my DetailViewController.h implemented the protocol: @interface DetailWebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> and added the shouldStartLoadWithRequest. I also added webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad, these methods get called but I had to add webView.delegate = self; in the viewDidLoad method. Nothing happens when I click the link in the webView, my link is:  <a href="eft://?filename=Google.jpg"  class="button"><h1>View Image</h1></a>. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know if it might be related to the URL. What's that "eft" thing? Try with a more common URL. like `http://www.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

Take care, this method is depecrated :
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Also, be sure to have your app delegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method to return YES or if your delegate implements the applicationDidFinishLaunching:, your code won't get called :

This method is not called if the delegate returns NO from its implementation of the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method. if your application implements the applicationDidFinishLaunching: method instead of application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, this method is called to open the specified URL after the application has been initialized.